# Filters with AND on nested resources

Tags: elasticsearch

My problem is : Elasticsearch count is not the same than my database.

I indexed "users" table, each user can have one or many apps_events :

```
curl localhost:9200/users/_count
{"count":190291,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0}}

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users
count : 190291
```

=> Same count, everything is ok !

But, when I do a search on 2 filters, one term and one terms one the nested resource :

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/users/user/_search?load=&size=10&pretty' -d '
{
"query": {
  "match_all": {
  }
},
"filter": {
  "and": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "apps_events.type": [
          "sale"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "term": {
        "apps_events.status": "active"
      }
    }
  ]
},
"size": 10
}

total : 63756
```

And in my database :

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users_id))
FROM
  apps_event
WHERE
  apps_event_state_id = 1 AND apps_event_project_id = 2;

count : 63340
```

Because in fact, elasticsearch SQL equivalent query is:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users_id))
FROM apps_event
WHERE apps_event_state_id = 1
AND users_id IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT(users_id) FROM apps_event WHERE apps_event_project_id = 2)

count : 63756
```

===> How I can do a simple "AND" for each resource ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best resource ever for "nested resource" :
http://www.spacevatican.org/2012/6/3/fun-with-elasticsearch-s-children-and-nested-documents/

Answer (score 0):

You've probably checked this, but is `apps_event_project_id` the right corollary to `apps_events.type`?  They don't seem the same on the surface, but you would know that for sure.  Also, does `users_id` map directly to ES `_id`?  It could be that you've got duplicates in your index which inflate its count.

Comment: Yes no duplicate but I finally found the problem, apps_events is a nested ressource and when you search with elasticsearch like that, in really its :

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(users_id)) FROM apps_event WHERE apps_event_state_id = 1 AND users_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(users_id) FROM apps_event WHERE apps_event_project_id = 2);
total : 63756

Comment: Thanks for following up.  I wasn't even thinking about the nesting!